# Trying to Hit an HTTP request on a specific instance using cloud foundry cli tool

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcf

As part of my POC ,I am trying to hit an http request in pcf  using cf cli tool , Sometimes I get proper response as expected sometimes I get below error :
****400 Bad Request: Requested instance ('1') with guid ('aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa') does not exist for route ('example-route.cf.com').**
I have 3 routes available for my application deployed in pcf and for one of the route sometimes it generates the above error .
I followed the below steps (Cf cli is installed on my machine) :

1.   Run command prompt as administrator

Login to CF CLI using command : “cf login” if you want to select a specific pcf env then use
cf login -a urlOfPCFenv

It will ask for your used id and password ,provide the correct credentials and you will get a message on terminal window : Authenticating...  OK

2. ```
      In a terminal window, retrieve the global unique identifier (GUID) of your app by 
   running:cf app <App-Name> --guid
   ```

   the output will be like a combo of number and words "12345678-1234-4ab4-1234-
   7a8b9c08d112" and <App-Name> is your application name
3. ```
      From the terminal output record the guid of your app.
   ```
4. ```
      List the app instances and retrieve the index number of the instance you want to hit on 
      by  running the below command :                                                                                                                       
      cf app <App-Name>
   ```
5. ```
      From the terminal output, record the index number of your instance (mentioned as # next 
      to state)
   ```
6. ```
      Trigger curl request to hit an api to a specific instance :                                                                                        
     curl -H <Authorization: Bearer <jwt>" -H  "X-Cf-App-Instance":"<APP-GUID>:                              
     <INSTANCE-INDEX-NUMBER>" -X  <Request-Mapping> <Api-Uri>

   **Eg :**  curl -H "Authorization: Bearer 0003uNnMOXUiYQLRliaxjiX6xbDR"
           -H "X-Cf-App-Instance":"3XXXXX37-48ac-495b-919d-474XXXXXXXX9:0" 
    -X GET https://iXXXXXXXs.api.xxxx.net/app-api-proxy/getDetailsById/XXXXXXX-XXXXX-atr56
   ```

I followed above steps but sometimes I get below error :
**400 Bad Request: Requested instance ('1') with guid ('aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa') does not exist for route ('example-route.cf.com').**

Request you to help with this or if you can suggest any other approach to hit an http request on a specific instance ,It would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Could be a lot of things. 1. Check `cf events` and see if you have applications crashing. You may have three instances, but if instances are crashing and restarting they'll be out of the rotation. This command will show you if instances have been crashing & restarting. Also, `cf logs` would show restarts too 2. `cf logs` can also help to show you if the request makes it to your app, you could have a routing issue somewhere. If it makes it, you'll see an `[RTR]` entry. 3. Check the header, it should be `-H "X-Cf-App-Instance: app-guid:index"`, you have some extra double quotes in the example.

Comment: @DanielMikusa Yes I can see RTR entry when I get 400 Bad request and its for that particular route only-  :    2023-05-08T08:05:40.69+0100 [RTR/10] OUT abc-def-api-v1-0-abcapp.gtw.dev.paas.pnf.ssnbc.net - [2023-05-08T07:05:40.690952416Z] 
 "GET /actuator/health HTTP/1.1" 200 0 223 "-" "-" "100.64.224.3:13430" "172.31.22.2:61001" 
 x_forwarded_for:"100.64.224.3" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"1f2d4ce6-0d3a-4722-6c1e-ae4bc56ac2e9" 
9e03-d4hairs880d95" app_index:"0" 
 instance_id:"7234170abc-b581-47fb-7419-60a0" x_cf_routererror:"-"

Comment: @DanielMikusa So this is something related to PCF route configuration which is incorrect and thats why I get instance does not  exist for that particular route ?

Comment: @DanielMikusa I have only one instance running for this application

Comment: Yes, sounds like the system is just trying to tell you that it can't do whatever you're requesting. It's not clear why, you can check `cf events` to see if your app is crashing, that could account for why you don't have the expected instance count. Also, make sure you can route requests to the app in general. Lastly, if you have access you could review the Gorouter logs which might have more details about why it cannot route that request.